# Cannot import a method from a module in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

I have installed Tensorflow 2.0

```
print(tf.__version__)
2.0.0-alpha0
```

While I can use the to_categorical method I can not import it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(np.arange(4), num_classes = 4)
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

But when I try:

```
from tf.keras.utils import to_categorical
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-243-c8bac54e2863> in <module>()
----> 1 from tf.keras.utils import to_categorical

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'
```

Comment: Did you install keras also? https://keras.io/#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

or like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
to_categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical
```